# Filter result based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

This might seem pretty simple. But after spending sometime, I thought of sharing this. I have the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM UPGRADE_HISTORY
ORDER BY MERCHANT_ID, RELEASE_ID
```

`Release_ID` lists all the releases corresponds to a particular merchant. In my case, I need to retrieve the result set corresponding to the latest `RELEASE_ID` per each Merchant.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add some sample table data, the current result and the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
select uh.*
from upgrade_history uh
where uh.release_id = (select max(uh2.release_id)
                       from upgrade_history uh2
                       where uh2.merchant_id = uh.merchant_id
                      );
```

This returns one row per merchant, with the largest value of the release id.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. This works like magic :)

Comment: @CoolCK: If this answer solves your problem, you can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043), so it informs others that your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The intended query is

```
SELECT uh.* 
FROM UPGRADE_HISTORY uh
Where uh.RELEASE_ID = (SELECT MAX(RELEASE_ID) 
                       FROM UPGRADE_HISTORY 
                       WHERE MERCHANT_ID=uh.MERCHANT_ID) 
ORDER BY uh.MERCHANT_ID, uh.RELEASE_ID
```

Comment: Don't you mean `ORDER BY MERCHANT_ID, RELEASE_ID DESC`?

Comment: I assume this query is not correct,it would not result in data as required by OP.It would return data in order of release_ids in descending order without any relation to merchant_id

Comment: No @jarlh. The query in the answer is the right one. Whatever comes first in the `Order By` will be get the highest priority

Comment: Here for "Merchant A" i get results for both RELEASE_ID 1, and RELEASE_ID 2. For "Merchant B" there's no RELEASE_ID 2. SO for Merchant B, only RELEASE_ID 1 related results are listed. Here I need to restrict my results for, RELEASE_ID 2 on Merchant A and RELEASE_ID 1 on "Merchant B". How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query (should work):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM UPGRADE_HISTORY UH1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        MERCHANT_ID
        ,MAX(RELEASE_ID) RELEASE_ID
    FROM UPGRADE_HISTORY
    GROUP BY MERCHANT_ID
) UH2 ON 
UH2.MERCHANT_ID = UH1.MERCHANT_ID
AND UH2.RELEASE_ID = UH1.RELEASE_ID
```

Comment: Just mark whichever answer solved your query whether mine or anyone elses.

Answer (score 0):

```
select uh.*
from Upgrade_History Uh
where Release_ID>= All( Select Release_ID from Uh2
                        where Uh.Merchant_ID=Uh2.Merchant_ID)
```